# How to display "HelloWorld" using *.phtml file but helloworld must not direct written in .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to display "Hello world" in category page through .phtml file but condition is that hello world **must not** directly written on .phtml file. We can write any code in .phtml file and call that phtml file and it will display hello world.

So, how it is possible?

I guess that if I make .php file and make one function, and that function I call in .phtml file , is it possible? and then .phtml call in .xml .

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us why you want this (homework?), that way we can help you easier.

Comment: No bro... this is not homework, this is own work i tried myself but i cant solve its answer thats why i ask here. Thanks

Comment: just refer [this link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part5-series-model-blocks-layours) you'll get a clear idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create YourNameSpace_Test.xml in app/etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_Test>   <!-- Name of Module -->
            <active>true</active>  <!-- This says if the module is active or not -->
            <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- This says the location of the module i.e inside the local folder. It can also be community folder. -->
        </YourNameSpace_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in app/code/local/YourNameSpace/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </YourNameSpace_Test>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>YourNameSpace_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>  <!-- This is the URL
 of the module. i.e www.yourmagento.com/index.php/test will be the url of your module. -->
                </args>
            </test>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <unique_identifier module="YourNameSpace_Test">
                    <file>yournamespace_test.xml</file>
                </unique_identifier>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <test>
                <class>YourNameSpace_Test_Block</class>  <!-- Path of the
 Block Folder, where all php files are located related to view -->
            </test>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

in app/code/local/YourNameSpace/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class YourNameSpace_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
         $this->loadLayout();  //This function read all layout files and loads them in memory
    $this->renderLayout(); //This function processes and displays all layout phtml and php files.
    }
}
```

in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/yournamespace_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="content"> <!-- block name inside which you need to display hello world -->
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>yournamespace_test/catalog/yournamespace_test.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

in app/design/frontend/default/default/template/yournamespace_test/catalog/yournamespace_test.phtml

```
<div>
    <?php
        echo $this->getContent(); 
    ?>
</div>
```

in app/code/local/YourNameSpace/Block/Test.php

```
<?php
class YourNameSpace_Test_Block_Test extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getContent()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

> this is the best way to do it. else simply create a `public function yourFunction(){ return "Hello World"; }` in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Category\View.php
>   and call that function as `<?php echo $this->yourFunction(); ?>` in app/code/design/frontend/default/default/catalog/category/view.phtml
>   But always remember editing the core is a very bad idea!

Comment: Thanks... i did whole step but where helloworld will display?

Comment: @Shatish i guess this is not correct path 'app/code/design/frontend/default/default/catalog/category/view.phtml' plz tell me correct one..

Comment: Thanks brother your 2nd way working bt i lost my all product... :)

Comment: lost your product? I don understand that!

Comment: in the first method, in yournamespace_test.xml you need to replace "block.name" (4th line) with the name of the block in which you need hello world to get displayed.
eg: "product.info"

Comment: ya, i lost product and only display hello world becoz i make my own view.phtml then i copy from base and update then it working.. bt i guess its not correct way becoz it is a changes on core file.

Comment: that's what i said, modifying view.phtml in default isn't a big problem, but you shouldn't modify View.php.

So follow the first method (see the edit). then hello will be displayed anywhere near product name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9398/discussion-between-michel06-and-shathish)

Comment: glad you got it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I can give a try.
You can have this in one of your xml layout files:

```
<catalog_category_view><!--in the category view page-->
    <reference name="content"><!--in the content area-->
        <block type="core/template" name="helloworld" as="helloworld" template="path/to/template.phtml"><!--create a block-->
            <action method="setMessage" translate="message"><!--set a message and translate it-->
                <message>Hello world</message><!-- the text-->
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

And your `path/to/template.phtml` should be located in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/template` and it should look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessage();?>
```

This should give you the desired result (if I have understood what your desired result is).

Comment: yes this is a quick workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This?

hello.phtml file:

```
<?php

include_once 'simple.php'; 
echo get_saying();

?>
```

simple.php file:

```
<?php 

function get_saying() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: What about file location? where file will be located?
and how i will call .phtml in xml?

Comment: even if this works, it's not a good practice to create simple php files in magento. You should work with blocks, or helpers on this one.

Comment: @Marius ya, i create block and trying to solve out but yet nothing done..