# Adding new page with new form

Tags: magento-1.9, page

I am trying to create new page to display a new form, but I have no idea where and how to start

My idea is to make form include fields that allow users to add jobs if they are looking for **employees**

- Make a drop-down list of the main job sections that will be identified by the admin in advance
- extra fields such as city of job and some description

How can I add these fields to database in order to re-display it after having approval from the admin

Comment: Did you create any module on this

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create a frontend module then you customise it with your form, [exemple](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5155/48355).

2) You create the admin interface to save your jobs in database and to retrieve them in front [exemple](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers/).

Good luck.